# WebView working in background

Tags: android, android-webview

I made app to watch YouTube in background. It's working when i turn off the screen, but when i minimize app - it's stopped. I did it with Service. Do you have any ideas how to do it right?

There is my code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       MainActivity.displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = MainActivity.displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        MainActivity.displayYoutubeVideo.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Watching Youtube in the background does not make sense. When in the backgound, nothing is "watchable". The activity is no longer active. [Android Dev. Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) says

> As the user begins to leave the activity, the system calls methods to dismantle the activity. In some cases, this dismantlement is only partial; the activity still resides in memory (such as when the user switches to another app), and can still come back to the foreground.
>
> If the user returns to that activity, the activity resumes from where the user left off. The system’s likelihood of killing a given process—along with the activities in it—depends on the state of the activity at the time.

So the behavior you are facing is there by design.

Your suggestion you do that via services is also bad idea. First, Services were designed to help you run long processes on the background without freezing the UI. But you want the UI to run on the background when no one is attending to it.

Secondly, Services have been problematic with recent android versions and are officially discouraged and have grim future. [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) is encouraged for Background tasks.

> Do you have any ideas how to do it right?

I don't know how exactly you are doing this, so I will give general view. Android will manage life cycle of your activities and you are in charge of data. If you are somehow having data from youtube, then you can store them in the [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) object so that when the Activity is active you can resume from where you left last time.

I don't suggest you try somehow to play videos on the background. It does not make sense at all!